# android search view shows default icon

Tags: android, icons, default, searchview

I have used material search view from github.(https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView).I followed the code in it.But when I try to run the app the default search view is shown instead of the search icon in the drawable.Below is the code.Screenshot is also included.
materialsearchview(xml):

```
<com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="Search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Java code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
       materialSearchView.setMenuItem(menuItem);
 materialSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am assuming this is the icon you want to show `android:icon="@drawable/search"`?

Comment: But I get the above default search icon in the screenshot

Comment: whats the expected icon?

Comment: The icon is white in color

Comment: maybe the image tint is changed, based on theme?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#8C9EFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#903F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="arrow">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="base">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="hint">#ffffff</color>
</resources>

Comment: Does it has has anything to do with the above style

Comment: @Selvin I removed appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView".Now it works fine.

Comment: ah you were using the default support searchview

Comment: But now when I click it the background of searchview is grey in color.Can I change that

Comment: I will include the screen shot